# March breaking changes, getting app access_token from new endpoint

Tags: access-token, facebook-access-token

The breaking change [this month](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) is that apps will no longer be returned for `/me/accounts` and that we should not be using `/me/applications/developer` to get applications but this endpoint does not return access_tokens for the applications but `/me/accounts` does. The Graph API reference documentation [does not even list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) `/me/applications/developer` so I am at a loss for how to actually replace /me/accounts as I need the access_token for applications to get insight data and other [information for the application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/).

Does anyone know how to get an access_token for a developer's app after the breaking change?

All of these endpoints require an application access_token, how does one get one?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are still experiencing the "old/current" endpoint at `/me/accounts` and `/me/applications/developer` is that you must enable these changes when you are ready. On March 6th, these changes will be automatically enabled if you have not already done so. Go to your app -> edit settings -> advanced and "enable" the March 2013 changes.

As far as the REST API is concerned, you should not be building on it anymore, as it will be deprecated in the future. You should only build on the Graph API now.

If you can't find docs on the endpoint for new features, you can always use the Graph API Explorer for example responses.

Comment: I meant the graph api, sorry, I updated the post. Thanks for the info I will try this.

Comment: Added the Graph API Explorer explanation.

Comment: No I still do not get an access_token from this endpoint even after I turned on breaking changes for march in the advanced app settings.

Comment: So it turns out that there's an entirely new way to get access tokens for apps and that it requires the application secret which you're not supposed to give out. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/  I can either ask users to give me their app secret (a no-no) or ask them to give me an access token they generated themselves).

Comment: So I will mark this answer as the answer since we figured it out in the comments, maybe you want to update your answer with my comment, I don't like answering my own questions. :P

Comment: It kind of sucks though that there's no easy way to get an access token, we want to show dashboards for user applications, but getting the access_token for apps is insane.

Comment: The (soon to be removed) tokens on the /me/accounts endpoint are not app access tokens as far as i know, they were page access tokens for the app's profile page. App profile pages were removed in February 2012, though the tokens for them were still valid.